# Does CQL Datastax 5.1 Solr search asking for facets require 2 queries?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to perform a Faceted search on Datastax 5.1 Solr via CQL as defined here [1]: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchJSON.html

In the docs it mentions that the faceting information is returned in a result set "*formatted as a single row with each column corresponding to the output of a facet (either field, query, or range)*"

I don't see that any search results are returned when asking for facets.  You only get the faceting counts.

**Does this mean I have to execute 2+ CQL statements?**  One to get the search results (the found documents information) and a second query to get the faceting information (the aggregated counts)?  And since I am wanting to facet on 3 dimensions this seems to imply that I will need to execute 4 total CQL statements.

This seems rather inefficient.  I hope I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of DSE 5.1, you must issue separate queries to retrieve both rows and facets using CQL and `solr_query`.